# Mapping Drives To Your SQL Script NET USE

Tags: sql, sql-server, xp-cmdshell, net-use

I do a lot of work with the file system in my SQL scripts. After a lot of effort, the only way I'm able to get all my network shares and NAS devices to be available to my SQL scripts is to start the script off with a "Net Use" command to map a drive letter.

I find this annoying to work with and sometimes unreliable.

I use something like this at the top of my scripts / stored procedures:

```
exec xp_cmdShell 'net use S: \\nas1\Data pass1234 /user:administrator /PERSISTENT:YES'
```

After I execute this, then the S:\ drive is available for me to work with.

*Does anyone have a more elegant solution to this that is easier to set up?*

Side note: I don't have a domain controller.

Comment: If you run the SQL Server service under your credentials it'll be able to access your mount points instead.

Comment: I have no domain controller so how would i access things that are outside of of the computer?  I need different credentials for different things.  Windows credentials I have setup on the server don't work inside of sql.

Comment: You could use this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1574/automatically-running-stored-procedures-at-sql-server-startup/ to run that net use code at startup. Then the SQL Server  service account should be authenticated then you can just use the drive letter or UNC path

Comment: **how would i access things that are outside of of the computer? "* with the UNC path, or drive letter, as you've already mounted them under your credentials, which the instance is now running under.